# recovering order from samples

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation, combinatorics

I have a pool of balls of 30 different color patterns(solid green, green and red striped, etc), and I also have 6 boxes ordered from 1 to 6. Now randomly I select 6 balls out of the pool and put each ball in one box so that each box contains exactly one ball. And among the 6 balls, the color pattern of each ball can be different from or the same as color pattern of other balls in other boxes. Now I want you to guess the color pattern of the ball in each box by doing the following:

Every time you make a request to me and I will randomly select 3 balls and display the balls in front of you in the same order of the box order. You can make unlimited requests.

The problem is how to tell the color pattern of the ball in each box by making least requests, I feel like there should be a well-known algorithm for this problem, but I can not find any. Has anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a lot of statistics in this. First of all, I would make the simplifying assumption that (if you don't know which colour balls are present) the only colours and patterns available are those which you have seen.

Now write down, or work out how to calculate, a formula that gives you the probability of the observed data given the listing of which balls are present in which boxes.

Now all you have to do is find the combination of balls in boxes that gives the highest probability to the observed data, and hope that as you get more and more data the right answer wins out.

You could think of this as a generic optimisation problem, and try hill-climbing from multiple random starts, or genetic programming, or whatever your favourite heuristic is.

Or you could do a bit more web-searching about statistics and recognise that this is a missing data problem, where the hidden data is the knowledge of which box each sampled ball came from. Statisticians often solve hidden data problems with the EM algorithm. There is an introduction for mathematicians at http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/pmr/docs/EM.pdf. Your problem can be thought of as a simple case of a hidden Markov model, with the hidden state being the box which produced a particular ball.